# Doctrine: Get a random name from a table of names

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have a SQL table with only two columns: "nameid" and "name".  I want to get a random name out of the database.

Before I did this via:

```
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM nametable",$db);
    $number = mysql_num_rows($result);
    $random = rand(1,$number);
    list($name) = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT name FROM nametable WHERE nameid=$random",$db));
```

How can I do the same with Doctrine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL has a function for generating random floating point values [`RAND()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand). When sorting by this, the names will be randomly-ordered. After this, you simply select the first, randomly-ordered name.

```sql
SELECT name FROM nametable ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

With Doctrine, this could be done using

```php
$name = Doctrine::getTable('nametable')
  ->createQuery()
  ->select('name')
  ->orderBy('RAND()')
  ->fetchOne();
```

Comment: Thanks!   I don't suppose you know how that would appear in CodeIgniter2+Doctrine2..? :)

Comment: I believe using Doctrine with CodeIgniter will be the same as above. If you want to use Codeigniter's Active Record, it'd be something like `$this->db->select('name')->from('nametables')->order_by('name','random')->limit(1)`.